The [asphalt-9-legends] tag should be renamed to [asphalt-legends-unite]
In a recent update, the game Asphalt 9: Legends had a name change to show the new cross-play features, and the title was changed to Asphalt Legends Unite.
To avoid confusion, the tag name should be changed too, to match the game’s new name.

Renamed asphalt-9-legends to asphalt-legends-unite and made the former a synonym.
